# Div relative positioning issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

The HTML:

```
<div id="broadcast">
    <div id="broadcast_header">
        Neighbourhood Broadcast
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#broadcast_header
{
 background-color: #A0522D;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Firefox: All fine, header appears 20px above the div, its cool.
IE: Refuses to show `div(broadcast_header)`!

Overflow: visible
`doctype` definition: Given

My input: Suppose change top to - `top: -5px;` It shows the div(header) partially.
Thank you :].

Comment: Please change your Title, though it might be true doenst "go" with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Add `body { margin:0 }` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This works differently. The surrounding element (#broadcast) has to have the position: relative; property. Then you can position (#broadcast_header) relative to this one by using position: absolute;

```
#broadcast_header
{
    background-color: #A0522D;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#broadcast
{
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Broadcast is already static, which allows its children to be moved about. Also, absolute positioning will negatively (and unnecessarily) affect the flexibility of your layout.

Comment: And where does the question mention that #broadcast is static?